# Is it possible to add a dimension to a numpy.ndarray that its shape becomes (n,m,1)?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

For example:

```py
xlist = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
xarr = np.array(xlist)
```

The shape of `xarr` is (2,4).

Is it possible to reshape it to (2,4,1), so that I can use `xarr[i][j][0]` to get an element?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

```
xnew = np.rehshape(xnew, (2, 4, 1)) # slow but can handle non numpy
xnew = xarr.reshape((2, 4, 1))      # can create a VIEW
xarr[:,:,np.newaxis]  # (2, 4, 1)   # create a VIEW
xarr.shape = (2, 4, 1)              # fast, changes original array
```

---

Some performance test, all operations are invariant for small to medium sized arrays.

[image]

Comment: When the `shape` attribute assignment is valid, `ndarray.reshape` only creates a view, not a copy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, never realized that

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
out = xarr[..., None]
```

Or:

```
out = xarr.reshape(2, 4, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]],

       [[5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.atleast_3d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_3d.html#numpy.atleast_3d) in this case.  As a bonus, it will also handle 1-d arrays (although a n-length 1d array will end up with shape `(1,n,1)` - which is probably what you'd want in this case anyway)

```
np.atleast_3d(xarr).shape
Out[]: (2, 4, 1)
```